# How to split configuration files away from jar with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to Gradle, in new project, I try to use Gradle 4 to manage and compile project. Task installDist is used to generate distribution folder. Gradle compress classes and all configurations into jar file, it works fine, but I want a jar only with classes and configuration in a standalone folder.

Here is my source folder structure:

```
src
--main
  --java
  --resources
```

Here is current dist folder structure:

```
build
--install
  --${project.name}
    --bin
    --lib
```

But I want sth below:

```
build
--install
  --${project.name}
    --bin
    --lib
    --resources
```

And I guess start script should be modified too, now I write a CreateStartScripts task like this:

```
task testServer(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    mainClassName = 'com.xxx.test.Server'
    applicationName = 'test-server'
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'tmp')
    classpath = jar.outputs.files + project.configurations.runtime
}
```

Could someone help me to write Gradle scripts?

Answer (score 0):

3 modification in build.gradle:

1. Suppress the configuration files to be built into jar:

   ```
   processResources {
       // if you have any other file suffix, append them below
       exclude '*.properties', '*.xml'
   }
   ```
2. Copy configuration files into dist folder:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'distribution'

   installDist.doLast {
       copy {
           from 'src/main/resources/'
           // $rootProject.name defined in settings.gradle
           into "$buildDir/install/$rootProject.name/resources"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add resources folder to classpath:

   ```
   task testServer(type: CreateStartScripts) {
       mainClassName = 'com.XXX.XXX.TestServer'
       applicationName = 'test-server'
       outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'tmp')
       classpath = jar.outputs.files + project.configurations.runtime
       classpath += files('src/main/resources')
       // gradle find all classpath files under install/${projectname}/lib defaultly
       // replace lib/resources with resources, thank [Fadeev's solution][1]
       doLast {
           def windowsScriptFile = file getWindowsScript()
           def unixScriptFile = file getUnixScript()
           windowsScriptFile.text = windowsScriptFile.text.replace('%APP_HOME%\\lib\\resources', '%APP_HOME%\\resources')
           unixScriptFile.text = unixScriptFile.text.replace('$APP_HOME/lib/resources', '$APP_HOME/resources')
       }
   }
   ```